# How to call a laravel factory dynamically?

Tags: laravel, eloquent, laravel-8, laravel-seeding, laravel-factory

I have the following seeder.

```
User::factory(100)
    ->has(Loan::factory()->count(5))
    ->has(Transaction::factory()->count(5)
    ->has(TransactionDetail::factory()->count(1), 'transaction_detail'))
    ->create();
```

Now I want to call another Verification class based on a verified property in the User class. So verified could have three possible values - 'pending', 'unverified', 'verified'. Now when it's verified or pending, I want to create a Verification class. But when it's unverified, I don't want to call that class. Something like this...

```
User::factory(100)
    ->($user->verified !== 'unverfied') ? has(Verification::factory()) : null
    ->has(Loan::factory()->count(5))
    ->has(Transaction::factory()->count(5)
    ->has(TransactionDetail::factory()->count(1), 'transaction_detail'))
    ->create();
```

Now, I know this syntax doesn't make any sense. But I am just trying to explain my problem.
How do I call this verification factory based on $user->verified?
Thanks in advance.